# Changing CSS based on querystring

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, is it possible to swap the whole css file with another css file based on a querystring parameter?

For example, if the url is
http://mysite.com/page1.php?style=1

This should use style1.css

If the url is
http://mysite.com/page1.php?style=2

This should use style2.css

How can this be done with jquery

Comment: Why the arbitrary jQuery requirement? How do you know that jQuery provides a valid solution to this?

Comment: Since it looks like you are using PHP, I'd recommend detecting the query string there and changing your stylesheet accordingly. Using jQuery, there may be a flash of unstyled content while it loads and changes the CSS files.

Comment: if I said, "can this be done with jquery", I would have gotten strange answers like "yes", without out showing how it can be done with jquery.  I would prefer not to use raw javascript.

Comment: @oshirowanen: FWIW, it's unlikely that any Javascript at all is your best approach. Why not do it in PHP?

Comment: Basically, the pages already exist, thousands of them.  I don't want to have to go and edit every single page.  But at the same time, I need all the old pages to keep the old style sheet.  I want the old pages to only use the new style sheet if they are requested from a certain page.

Comment: So I don't know if javascript is the best solution for this.

Comment: That you lacked the foresight to design your code modularly in the first place is no excuse to take the wrong approach now!

Comment: @oshirowanen as @Rob says, doing this on server side would be vastly better, a JS based solution might not work optimally, and won't work at all if JS is turned off. It might be worth editing each PHP file, and adding a link to a central include file that defines which style sheet gets included

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, how does this comment solve the "current" problem?

Comment: @oshirowanen: Comments are not answers. See my answer for the solution.

Comment: @Pekka, I understand that using a serverside approach would be best, but trying to edit 1000's of serverside files is out of the question unfortunately.

Comment: @oshirowanen: How will that be different if you use Javascript? Where will you instead make the changes?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, I have no idea, which is why I have posted the quesiton here.

Comment: I have updated the question.  The previous question did not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't strictly answer the question posed, but it best solves the problem:

Do it in PHP.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <?php
      if (!is_numeric(@$_GET['style']))
         die("No style ID given!");

      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style' . $_GET['style'] . '.css" />';
      ?>
   </head>

   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 Though I'd probably do `if (!is_numeric(@$_GET['style'])) $style = 0;` and use a default stylesheet rather than ending the script because the query parameter didn't exist.

Comment: I have updated the question.  The previous question did not make sense.

Comment: @oshirowanen: I think you should have deleted it and created a new one. This is barely related.

Answer (score 2):

link - http://mysite.com/page1.php?style=2

css - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />`

```
if ( location.search )
{
   var style = location.search.replace("?","").split("=");
   if ( style[0] === "style" && parseInt( style[1]) === 2 )
   {
      $("link").attr("href","style2.css");
   }
}
```

Based on your question before the edit. Tested on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the server-side solution given by Tomalak

However, if you want to check the query string client side there are possibilities, check out this one for example:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: I have updated the question.  The previous question did not make sense.

Comment: Hehe question makes more/other sense now, but you should consider deleting the current question and re-asking the question you wanted to as: with all the current replies I don't think this thread can be helpful anymore to ppl who stumble to this corner of the interwebz ;)